# vue apollo composite oe batch queries -- possible?

Tags: vue-apollo

Has anyone found away of doing composite queries with Vue Apollo (Apollo boost)?

**A composite batch query**

I have an array if ids [ 12, 34, 56, 76, 76, …] and for each id I need to send a graphQL query. I could end up with a 500 queries being called one after the other.

Instead I want to batch them (or send them all at the same time) using aliases. Something like

```
[
  first: User(id: "12") {
    name
    email
  },
  second: User(id: "34") {
    name
   email
  },
....
....
oneHundred: User(id: "34") {
    name
    email
  }
]
```

With the results being popped into an array. E.g.

```
this.users.pop(second)
```

I’ve done a fair bit of reading and searching. I found this that hints that it can be done

[enter link description here](https://www.howtographql.com/advanced/2-more-graphql-concepts/)

Any help out there?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in 3 parts.

1. Does the server recognise batch requests? Apollo server does by default
2. Set up the client in your app to handle batches
3. Create the queries on the fly.

Creating a Vue Apollo client:

```
import VueApollo from 'vue-apollo'
import Vue from 'vue';
import { ApolloClient } from 'apollo-client'
import { ApolloLink, split } from 'apollo-link'
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http'
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory'
import { BatchHttpLink } from 'apollo-link-batch-http';
import { getMainDefinition } from 'apollo-utilities'

const httpLink = new HttpLink({ uri: HTTP_END_POINT });

const batchLink = new BatchHttpLink({ uri: HTTP_END_POINT });

const link = split(
  // split based on operation type
  ({ query }) => {
    const { kind, operation } = getMainDefinition(query)
    return kind === 'OperationDefinition' && operation === 'subscription'
  },
  httpLink,
  batchLink,
)

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: ApolloLink.from([link]),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  connectToDevTools: true
})
```

Example of sending of a batch of queries inside a Vue component:

```
methods: {
    fetchUsers() {
        [<a list of user ids>].forEach(id => {
            this.$apollo.query({
              query: USER_QUERY,
              variables: { id },
            }).then(d => {
              console.table(d.data.User)
              this.users.push(d.data.User)
            }).catch(e => console.log(e));
      });
},
}
```

The actual query looks like:

```
import gql from "graphql-tag";

export const USER_QUERY = gql`
  query User($id: String!) {
    User(id: $id) {
      firstName
      lastName
    }
  }
```